# Calculation of humidity ratio by vapor partial pressure

Tags: pressure, ideal-gas, evaporation, humidity

I've been looking around for a way to calculate the humidity ratio by the partial vapor pressure and the atmospheric pressure of the environment.

I found a procedure for such calculation on engineering toolbox (https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/humidity-ratio-air-d_686.html).
There, it is explained that:

> Based on the Ideal Gas Law, the humidity ratio can be expressed as:
>
> x = 0.62198 pw / (pa - pw)
>
> where
>
> pw = partial pressure of water vapor in moist air (Pa, psi)
>
> pa = atmospheric pressure of moist air (Pa, psi)

However, it is very unclear to me where they got the value `0.62198` from. I couldn't find any explanation as to why this value is used and how is it obtained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the ratio between the molar mass of water (about 18.01528g/mol) and the one of dry air (about 28.97g/mol).